# Derivative of $t \mapsto (X+tY)^m$

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Let $X, Y \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$. Is the following true?

$$\frac{d}{dt}(X+tY)^m = m(X+tY)^{m-1}Y$$

I believe it's true if $X$ and $Y$ commute, but what about if they don't? How do I calculate the derivative in such a case?

Comment: Are you taking the derivative evaluated at $t=0$?

Comment: If they don't commute and you differentiate in $0$, then the result is $YXXX\ldots + XYXX\ldots + \ldots + X\ldots XY$. Just use Leibnitz rule $(AB)'=A'B+AB'$.

Answer (score 0):

For typing convenience, define the matrix variable
$$
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
A=\big(X+tY\big) \qiq dA=Y\,dt
$$
Let's assume that you are dealing with some analytic function
$$\eqalign{
\def\Sk{\sum_{k=0}^\infty}
f(z) &= \Sk c_k z^k \\
f'(z) &= \Sk kc_k z^{k-1} \\
}$$
Apply this function to the $A$ matrix and calculate its derivative
$$\eqalign{
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\Sj{\sum_{j=\o}^k}
\def\Sm{\sum_{j=\o}^m}
\def\deriv#1#2{\frac{d #1}{d #2}}
F &= f(A) \;=\; \Sk c_kA^k \\
dF &= \Sk c_k \Sj A^{k-j}\:\c{dA}\:A^{j-\o} \\
 &= \Sk c_k \Sj A^{k-j}\c{Y}A^{j-\o}\;\c{dt} \\
\deriv{F}{t} &= \Sk c_k \Sj A^{k-j}YA^{j-\o} \\
}$$
For your particular function, $\,c_m=\o\,$ and all of the other coefficients are zero.

Therefore
$$\eqalign{
\deriv{F}{t} &= \Sm A^{m-j}YA^{j-\o}
\qquad\qquad \\\\
}$$

---

$\sf NB\!:\:$ If $\,X,Y\,$ commute, then the derivative can be simplified to
$$\eqalign{
\deriv{F}{t}
  &= \left(\Sk k c_k A^{k-\o}\right) Y
  \;\;\equiv\; f'(A)\cdot Y
}$$